# Is the supremum of addition and multiplication of functions the addition and multiplication of supremum of functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be three real functions defined in $X \subset \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to know if is it true that
$$
\sup_{x \in X}
|f(x)+g(x)h(x)|
\leq
\sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|
+
\sup_{x \in X} |g(x)|
\sup_{x \in X} |h(x)|
.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true by the triangular inequality: for all $x\in X$,
\begin{align}
|f(x)+g(x)h(x)|&\leq |f(x)|+|g(x)h(x)|=|f(x)|+|g(x)||h(x)|\\
&\leq
\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|+\sup_{x\in X}(|g(x)||h(x)|)\\
&\leq
\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|+\sup_{x\in X}|g(x)|\sup_{x\in X}|h(x)|.
\end{align}

Comment: A thing to note: $\sup |ab| \leq \sup |a|\sup |b|$

Comment: @AlvinLepik Good point. I edited the answer.

Comment: @RobertZ my question is $\sup_{x \in X} |f(x)+g(x)h(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)| + \sup_{x \in X} |g(x)| \sup_{x \in X} |h(x)|$, is your answer the same?

Comment: @MateyMath, Yes, because the RHS in the last line does not depend on $x$.

Comment: ok @RobertZ thanks for your answer